# Excel como base de datos de viajes(logistica) - Quiero mejorar la estructura de datos del mismo

Tags: excel, estructuras-de-datos

Que tal comunidad quisiera si pudieran darme sus recomendaciones para mejorar una base de datos de viajes de unidades de carga que llevo.

Lo que quiero lograr es darle un estructura a los datos para que pueda utilizarlos para crear gráficos en Excel o porque no BI para mostrar la productividad y o actividad de los viajes realizados.

Entiéndase por viaje, un vehículo de carga que sale de sucursal, realiza todas sus entregas y regresa.

Cabe destacar tengo otro libro en donde tengo en forma de "lista" la información de "Chofer de viaje" - "Viaje" - "Ruta", ya que esos datos varían pero también se repiten.

Gracias por su ayuda.

[image: Captura de la base de datos como se visualiza a simple vista]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EN tu tabla debes registrar la mayor cantidad de información, como hora de salida planificada, hora de salida real, hora de llegada plan, real, etc. y todos los hitos que tengas, debes tener una registro por viaje.
con eso armas lo que quieras.
Por ejemplo, el tiempo de viaje en si no es un dato a ingresar, lo debes obtener de la resta de las horas de inicio y fin, si registras esas horas, luego puedes analizar productividad o cancelaciones por rango de hora, día de la semana, etc.